# Implementing a child package in android manifest

Tags: android, package

Since I cant seem to find this anywhere is there anyone on here who can tell me how to do this? I'm trying to in essence make a Shared preference to be used in my app I want this to be set in a separate package so i cant be launched on its own. The code I'm working on is about 99% complete its just debugging stuff now.

Comment: please elaborate on what you are trying to do? you cannot installed artifacts into the pkg namespace other than that of your app.

Comment: Yes you just need to creat new package and put sharedPref classes there >> if you can ask question in detail then one can answer in detail too

Comment: You don't launch packages, you launch Activities. Why do you think you need to put your SharedPreferences in a different package?

Comment: Never mind it was a pointless idea in the long run.

Answer (score 0):

The reason behind my pointless idea before is that I am running this settings as a launcher that will hold my shared prefs which we all know shared prefs are a global thing with in the app itself so it was not worth it to run it as a child package since it would have been fine in the first one anyhow.